# Avoiding repetitive arguments in Java EE

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

**TL;DR** The question is about avoiding repetitive arguments in method signatures without performance degradation.

```
public void foo(Context context, Config config, Request request);
void helper(Context context, Request request);
void otherHelper(Context context, Config config, Request request);
```

I need signatures like this:

```
public void foo(Request request);
void helper(Request request);
void ohterHelper(Request request);
```

Configuration won't change very often, some arguments will be request scoped. Caches may have a broader, conversation scope etc.

I want to apply this idea to Java Enterprise environment.

It should be a bean with injected field `config` that calls other beans `f` and `g` (also with fields `config`) and concatenates results as in example. It should extend to many more fields like `config` (e.g. `context` or `cache`), but only request data from client is allowed in actual method signature (in this example there is none to be concise).

Lifecycle of all `config` fields should be managed so that all beans in see same `config` value for the duration of some externally managed scope (e.g. request to facade).

There may exist an EE pattern that solves this problem.

I am explicitly not looking for solutions using `ThreadLocal` as I want to be able to run tasks in parallel (if at all possible). I am also not looking for `AOP` and scoped beans (constant allocation and work for GC, I have done profiling before in similar situation).

I have feeling that solution might be an "lost art" today and may be as simple as proper container management (with dependency injection) of pooled of session beans. The trick would be for container to know how to manage lifecycle of `g` and `h` within `f` while injecting (or mutating) all fields when a scope changes (e.g. new request, new conversation).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming some way to get the config and context, set your current methods to private and create a public convenience function:

```
public void foo(Request request) {
  Context context = getContext();
  Config config = getConfig();
  foo(context, config, request);
}
```